# How to confirm from user if he wants to leave the page while filling form?

Tags: javascript, django

I am creating a form where user can fill data. Based upon the user's input and selected options I'm showing the next data to fill using js which works totally fine.

Now what I want is if the user presses the back or exit button accidentally. I want to confirm with the user if he really wants to exit from the current page.

Comment: Any chance of providing some source code to see how exactly you're going about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a [confirm dialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) to get user confirmation when the [beforeUnload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) is fired, which gets fired when the document is about to be unloaded from the DOM, which includes browser moving to another page or exiting the website.